# Cabal Test Suite with type detailed example

Tags: testing, haskell, cabal

I'm searching for a cabal package using the detailed Test-Suite interface to learn how to structure the code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [cabal documentation](http://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/#test-suites) contains examples for both the `detailed-1.0` and `exitcode-stdio-1.0` test interfaces. However, note that the detailed test interface isn't supported yet. Only the simpler `exitcode-stdio-1.0` interface is currently supported.

From [a recent mail thread](http://www.mail-archive.com/cabal-devel@haskell.org/msg07616.html) on the `cabal-devel` list (dated September 5, 2011):

> Ah, a rare case of premature documentation. That is, documentation for a
>   feature that is due, but not released yet. [...] No released version supports
>   the detailed interface yet. Just recently we think we've settled on the final
>   interface and will hopefully get that implemented in the darcs version soon.

Comment: They really should rip that out of the documentation, it's horrible misleading.

Answer (score 5):

Since I have been stumbling over this question quite a few times: With Cabal 1.20(1.18 ?), detailed-0.9 *is* supported, see for example https://github.com/michaxm/test-detailed-example. But since there has been quite some time witout it, the infrastructure around exitcode-stdio-1.0 (+ one of the supporting libs, e. g. hspec, hunit, ...) may still be superior.

See [How to use detailed-0.9 in cabal testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18343249/how-to-use-detailed-0-9-in-cabal-testing) as well.

Example of minimal .cabal contents for a detailed-0.9 test (using names of a default stack project) :

```
name:                test-detailed-example
version:             0.1.0.0
build-type:          Simple
cabal-version:       >=1.20

library
  hs-source-dirs:      src
  exposed-modules:     Lib
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7 && < 5
  default-language:    Haskell2010

test-suite test-detailed-example-test
  type:                detailed-0.9
  hs-source-dirs:      test
  test-module:         Spec
  build-depends:       base >= 4.7,
                       Cabal >= 1.20
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

Answer (score 0):

Haddock's cabal file includes a test-suite stanza; perhaps you could start there.