# Need some explanation about Distribution.TestSuite

Tags: haskell, cabal, test-suite

I’m looking for some examples or well-documented readings that describe how to use the `Distribution.TestSuite`. The current haddock documentation is quite poor and so is the userguide. I want to write tests for a project and run them through cabal. I do not want the `exitcode-stdio-1.0` test interface.

Any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, you're trying to use the `detailed-1.0` interface, but this is still not really ready for usage. There's a question from late 2011 about this, but sadly I don't think things have changed - [Cabal Test Suite with type detailed example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8266938/cabal-test-suite-with-type-detailed-example).

Is there any reason you don't want to use `exitcode-stdio`?

Comment: `exitcode-stdio` doesn’t have its own framework whereas `detailed-1.0` does