# Why does my HUnit test suite fail but pass successfully in Cabal?

Tags: unit-testing, haskell, hunit

If I have `test/Test.hs` with

```
module Main where

import Test.HUnit

test1 :: Test
test1 = TestCase $ assertEqual "Should be one" 1 5

test2 :: Test
test2 = TestCase $ assertEqual "Shold both be zero" 0 0

main :: IO Counts
main = runTestTT $ TestList [test1, test2, test1]
```

and a `.cabal` with

```
test-suite my-test
    type:               exitcode-stdio-1.0
    hs-source-dirs:     test
    main-is:            Test.hs
    build-depends:      base >= 4.8.1.0 && <4.9,
                        HUnit >= 1.3
    default-language:   Haskell2010
```

and I run `cabal test --show-details='always'` then I get

```
Test suite my-test: RUNNING...
### Failure in: 0
test/Test.hs:6
Should be one
expected: 1
 but got: 5
### Failure in: 2
test/Test.hs:6
Should be one
expected: 1
 but got: 5
Cases: 3  Tried: 3  Errors: 0  Failures: 2
Test suite my-test: PASS
```

Why does my test suite pass when I've had failures? Likewise, if I `cabal sdist` I get no warning that my tests have failed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [Cabal users' guide](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#test-suites),

> Test suites using the `exitcode-stdio-1.0` interface are executables that indicate test failure with a non-zero exit code when run; they may provide human-readable log information through the standard output and error channels.

You've defined

```
main :: IO Counts
main = runTestTT $ TestList [test1, test2, test1]
```

This runs tests, prints out test information, and then always exits successfully. If you want Cabal to know the test has failed, you need to capture the `Counts`, check for `errors` and `failures`, and exit with a non-zero status if you find such.

```
import System.Exit

main :: IO ()
main = do
  results <- runTestTT $ TestList [test1, test2, test1]
  if (errors results + failures results == 0)
    then
      exitWith ExitSuccess
    else
      exitWith (ExitFailure 1)
```

The `test-framework` package provides convenient `defaultMain` functions that do this sort of thing; you may want to consider that approach.

You should note that the `exitcode-stdio-1.0` interface is considered semi-deprecated; the Cabal maintainers recommend switching to their rather more Haskellian `detailed-0.9` interface.

Comment: I had looked into `detailed-0.9`, but [got the vibe](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18686329/656912) that it was less stable and hard to use.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius, could be. I've never messed with either; I've only done a bit of expansion of existing test suites in existing projects.

Comment: @dfeuer: I used your approach with `ExitSuccess` and `ExitFailure`, but it does not work for some reason if I run `cabal test --show-details='always'` - build says test suite : PASS even though there is one failure. Could you please recommend a workaround?

Comment: @altern, I suggest you ask a separate question with a full reproduction and link to this question. It's too hard to go into detail with comments, and it's impossible to diagnose the problem without code.